# Mod Rewrite - Force HTTPS and Rewrite Variable?

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, heroku

I am running on Heroku and have added Rewrite rules to clean up the URL and also force https. I am having a small issue when the url is rewritten from http to https and don't understand rewrite rules enough yet to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Current .htaccess on Heroku

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?id=$1 [QSA]
    ##Force SSL 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
```

When I visit https://example.com/12345 everything works great.
When I visit http://example.com/12345 the url is rewritten to https://example.com/12345?id=12345

I'd like http to rewrite to https://example.com/12345

What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you do not need the 2nd and 3rd rows. So your conf will be:

```
RewriteEngine On
##Force SSL 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
```

And I do not see any `RewriteRule` after the last `RewriteCond`.
Did you forget to add something like the following to your question or to your conf?

```
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=301]
```

Comment: I definitely need the 3rd line since it has another purpose mentioned in my question which is handling url parameters.

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd line do `12345?id=12345` if `REQUEST_FILENAME` is not a file and do have nothing with url parameters.